# In my Node , Express app, an update route is generating a range error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, error-handling

The following route is generating a deprecation message and a range error. I have been reading about both but still don't understand either.

```
// Update
app.put('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    req.body.blog,
    function (err, updatedBlog) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // res.redirect('/blogs');
      } else {
        res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id, { blog: updatedBlog });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Here is the error message in full

```
express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead app.js:89:13
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: { blog: [Object] }
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:248:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:239:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:642:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:753:5)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:951:10)
    at /home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/app.js:89:13
    at /home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4837:16
    at /home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2869:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at /home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4839:13
    at /home/jimmy/code/courses_tutorials/js_scratchpad/node_demos/blog_REST_demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2869:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can anyone explain this error and point me in the right direction? Thanks all!

Comment: Read about the actual arguments to `res.redirect`: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 1):

[`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) does not take objects as a parameter. It can optionally take a status (eg. `302`) which is probably what the function is trying to parse your object as.

Instead, you can just redirect the user to view the edited blog:

```
  res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is coming from incorrect arguments passed. First should be status and second - url. Currently, you are passing url, where status should be and some kind of object to url argument